# Display image from json response

Tags: php, json, api

Below is my json respone:

```
 {"Status":"OK","Result":"{\"Cookie\":MyCookie",\"Data\":{\"ItemPhotos\":[{
\"ITEMID\":\"MyItemsID",
\"ITEMIMAGE\":\"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\",
\"IMAGEID\":\"ImageID",
\"IMAGEDESCR\":\"xxx.jpg\",
\"IMAGETYPE\":\"TheImageType\",
\"IMAGESIZE\":\"320 x 240\"},]},
\"Messages\":[]}","Error":null,"ErrorCode":null,"Benchmark":0}
```

I want to diplay the image of json response and i use the code below unsuccessfully

```
$image=json_decode($decoded['Result']);
$path=$image->Data->ItemPhotos[0]->{'ITEMIMAGE'};
$icon=glob($path."*.jpeg");

foreach($icon as $img) {
    echo '<img src="'.$img.'" /><br />';
}
```

Comment: Your use of glob makes no sense in this context. The ITEMIMAGE field contains a base64 representation of the image. It's very obvious just from looking at it that it doesn't contain a path

Comment: @ADyson so how can i use this to display the image ?

Comment: This has two quick solutions. One is to persist your image and send the path, other is to send the JSON and create markup based on the JSON value (IMAGEDESCR, ITEMIMAGE) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two quick solutions for this. One is to persist the encoded image and append the path to the image src. Another solution is to process the json and use the base 64 processor in correct format eg:- 'data:image/png;base64,' + <base 64 encoded image>

or,

'data:image/jpg;base64,' + <base 64 encoded image>

I created a snippet that works with your use case. You have to refactor it a bit to accommodate your changes.

```php
<?php

// Lets assugme you receive this json response
$json = '{
        "ITEMIMAGE": "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",
        "IMAGEID": "ImageID",
        "IMAGEDESCR": "xxx.jpg",
        "IMAGETYPE": "TheImageType",
        "IMAGESIZE": "320 x 240"
}';

$decode = json_decode($json);
// you need base 64 processor
$processor = "";
if($decode->IMAGEDESCR == "xxx.jpg") {
    $processor = "data:image/jpg;base64,";
} elseif ($decode->IMAGEDESCR  == "xxx.png") {
    $processor = "data:image/png;base64,";
}

$img_src = $processor . $decode->ITEMIMAGE;

echo '<img src='.$img_src.'/>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `src` attribute for the `img` tag will be something like this

```
'data:image/png;base64,' + $path;
```

you must inform that the image is encoded base64 (I suppose it is) and also specify the kind of data (image/png) in my example

Comment: Yes but it would need to be using the variable the OP has (rather erroneously) called $path rather than $img, which is unlikely to contain anything meaningful (or even exist at all)

Comment: i tried     echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, + $path" /><br />';  and  appears the Handle broken image

Comment: @Karl you must check the type of the image, as I wrote. pheraps your image isn't a png. Adjust the part `data:` accordingly to your context.